# Subtract columns from two data frames based on a common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

1. Asia       34
2. America    74
3. Australia  92
4. Africa     44

df2 :

1. Asia       24
2. Australia  90
3. Africa     30

I want the output of df1 - df2 to be

1. Asia       10
2. America    74
3. Australia  2
4. Africa     14

I am getting troubled by this, I am newbie into pandas. Please help out.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.subtract.html) there is a fill parameter where you can add mission values which you can obtain from your frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with mapped second `Series` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['B'] = df1['B'].sub(df1['A'].map(df2.set_index('A')['B']), fill_value=0)
print (df1)
           A     B
0       Asia  10.0
1    America  74.0
2  Australia   2.0
3     Africa  14.0
```

If possible changed ordering of first column convert both first columns to index by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and subtract :

```
df2 = df1.set_index('A')['B'].sub(df2.set_index('A')['B'], fill_value=0).reset_index()
print (df2)
           A     B
0     Africa  14.0
1    America  74.0
2       Asia  10.0
3  Australia   2.0
```